# Saving UTF-8 text containing .gzip data stored in a string to file C++

Tags: c++, string, utf-8, gzip

As the the title suggests, with C++, I am having some issues saving UTF-8 text from a string.
I can confirm the string has the correct data, however I can't write it to a file without losing parts of the .gzip data.

Please note: 1. ofstream won't support utf-8.
             2. This is for windows only, no need for it to be universal.
             3. Prefer not to decompress the .gzip as it is mixed in with the string.

I am using this: http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2008/10/20/writing-utf-8-files-in-c/

Here is the code:

```
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;

std::wstring wide = converter.from_bytes(packetString); // Will not go past here for some reason.

std::ofstream testFile;

testFile.open("C:\\output", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

std::string outtext = to_utf8(wide);

testFile << outtext;

testFile.close();
```

I am having trouble getting this code to convert my string when it contains a mix of ASCII and UTF-8 and I'm really not sure why it happens to fail at the commented line.

Comment: can you make it more specific, or paste some code. Or what you expect from a response.

Comment: Without any relevant information, I would guess you forgot to open your stream in binary mode.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of information in the original post, I edited it and it should be up to par.

Comment: You cannot convert binary data to UTF-8. This makes no sense. Only text stored in a specific encoding can be converted to another encoding. Try `testFile.write(packetString.data(), packetString.size())`.

Comment: Man I feel really stupid right about now.  Thank you so much for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
testFile.write(packetString.data(), packetString.size())
```

I'm bad, this is what I needed.